# why char* why not bool* can be used in write function in c++ file I/O

Tags: c++, file, io, typecasting-operator

In this statement why cast x to char* and not to bool*-

```
out.write( (char*)&(x), sizeof(double) );
```

Comment: Probably from the fact that bool wasn't a standard C type when C++ was made and char* is used in C.

Comment: Why it should be `char*` is an understandable question. But I don't understand why you would instead expect it to be `bool*`.

Comment: Especially with `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: What do you want to happen with that code?

Comment: How is `out` defined? Why would you expect `bool*` to make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this statement why cast x to char* and not to bool* ...

It suspect you are thinking that a `bool`, conceptually a single bit, is the most basic data type in C++. That is not the case. Individual bits are not addressable in C++. The C++ memory model is organized around the concept of a byte, which must contain at least eight bits. By definition, a `char` (and related types `signed char` and `unsigned char`) is exactly one byte long.

That bits aren't addressable means the concept of a boolean data type doesn't quite fit into the memory model. Consecutive booleans either have gaps between them (which would be problematic for your proposed cast to `bool*`) or a boolean can contain far more values than just `false` and `true` (also problematic; a boolean that contains some value other than `false` or `true` is undefined behavior).

The C++ I/O model extends the byte-based memory model to I/O. A C++ I/O stream comprises a sequence of bytes (and sometimes multiple bytes in the case of wide chars) rather than a sequence of bits. This is why `std::basic_ostream::write` takes a pointer of some character type (typically `char`) and a size as the arguments.

Answer (score 6):

A boolean has two values: true and false.

Unless every byte in your buffer only has one of two values, this would be an exceedingly silly type to choose to represent arbitrary data.

`char` is treated as the conventional "some byte" type. Consequently, `char*` is the conventional "pointer to some bytes" type.

Comment: Also, `char*` is typically chosen as it accesses the data in one byte chunks. (As opposed to always using `int*` which would only be able to point at every fourth byte.